# How to create a function object from an ast.FunctionDef node?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to understand the process by which python code gets executed. Suppose the source has a function definition. Using `ast.parse()`, I parse it into an ast, which will contain an instance of the `FunctionDef` node class. This node instance is not a callable and is not the same as the function object. How can the function object, with all its dunder attributes, be created from this ast?

Comment: I want to know how to create the function object from the ast, if it is not the same as an ast node?

Comment: Right from the top of the `ast` module documentation: "An abstract syntax tree can be compiled into a Python code object using the built-in `compile()` function."

Comment: That gives me a code object which is not the same as a function object. I think I would need to further execute that code object with `exec()` to create the actual function object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't (as far as I know) compile an arbitrary individual AST node like a FunctionDef.  What you can do is compile the entire code snippet as a module, exec it in a provided namespace, and then access its contents, including the function.  Here's an example:

```
import ast

txt = """
def foo(x, y=2):
    z = x*y + 3
    print("z is", z)
    return z**2
"""

tree = ast.parse(txt, mode='exec')
code = compile(tree, filename='blah', mode='exec')
namespace = {}
exec(code, namespace)
```

Now `namespace` is the equivalent of the `__dict__` of a module containing the given code.  You can access and call the function:

```
>>> namespace['foo']
<function foo at 0x00000000023A2B70>
>>> namespace['foo'](2, 3)
z is 9
81
```

Note that if this is all you want to do, there's no need to use `ast` at all.  You can just compile the source string directly with `compile(tree, filename='blah', mode='exec')`.  And in fact there's no need to even involve `compile`, since you can just exec the source string directly with `exec(txt, namespace)`.  If your goal is just to get the final function object out, you don't really need access to the internal parse and compile steps; just exec the whole thing in a namespace and then grab the function from there.

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting. Thanks for making it clear. What happened to the output of the `print` in your example function?

Comment: @debashish: Oops, I accidentally trimmed it out when formatting the output.  I edited my example to include it, and make the `print` a bit more informative so the connection is more clear.

Comment: So this essentially shows how to parse a string (or template file) with python ast, compile it and then call a function within that ast.</SEO because I couldn't find this as easily as I wanted to ;)>

Answer (score 0):

In case the function is under a class, below code will help -
import ast

```
txt = """
class MyClass():
  def foo(x, y=2):
      z = x*y + 3
      print("z is", z)
      return z**2
"""

tree = ast.parse(txt, mode='exec')
code = compile(tree, filename='blah', mode='exec')
namespace = {}
exec(code, namespace)
val = "foo"
dict_item = namespace["MyClass"].__dict__.items()
for x,y in list(dict_item):
  if val == x:
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(type(x))
    print(type(y))
```