# I am trying to create endpoint by using flask in python, but i m getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

Here is my code-

```
if __name__=="__main__":
obj = MethodGeneration()
files = obj.get_python_files_with_keywords()
node = obj.get_file_node("firstDirectory/user.py")
classes = obj.get_classes(node)

for class_ in classes:
    print("Class name:", class_.name)
    methods = [n for n in class_.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
    for method in methods:
        print("method name:", method.name)
        if method.name != "random_method":
            url_rule = "/{0}".format(method.name)
            for arg in method.args.args:
                if  str(arg.arg) != "self":
                    url_rule = url_rule + "/" + "<{0}>".format(arg.arg)
            print("url rule {0}".format(url_rule))
            app.add_url_rule(url_rule, url_rule, method.name)
app.run(debug=True)
```

Method.name is string here, but how do i change it to function for this user.py class.

Here is the output I am getting, I could see that endpoint generation is looking fine. but as method.name is string. Do i need to provided any class details in add_url_rule?

```
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the method not the name

```
app.add_url_rule(url_rule, url_rule, method)
```

Comment: i tried that but then I get "TypeError: 'FunctionDef' object is not callable" error.

Comment: You'll have to create a function from your `ast.FunctionDef` object. Looks someone has already done that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759838/how-to-create-a-function-object-from-an-ast-functiondef-node).

Comment: Below thing helped me, it seems accessing function changes a lot with class - import ast

txt = """
class MyClass():
  def foo(x, y=2):
      z = x*y + 3
      print("z is", z)
      return z**2
"""

tree = ast.parse(txt, mode='exec')
# classes = [n for n in tree.body if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]
code = compile(tree, filename='blah', mode='exec')
namespace = {}
exec(code, namespace)
val = "foo"
dict_item = namespace["MyClass"].__dict__.items()
for x,y in list(dict_item):
  if val == x:
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(type(x))
    print(type(y))